# Selecting input and output caps and Schottky diode for buck convertor circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have searched and googled until my brain hurts. I am designing the circuit shown, which will operate from an automotive electrical system and I was trying to ensure a clean power supply for the convertor and the IC. The buck convertor gives a value of 33uH for the inductor, and shows an input and output cap as well as a schottky diode in the output circuit. However, it does not give vales for the capacitors or the schottky, or how to calculate them.

In my searches I have come up with widely varying information as to how to calculate, some of which ask for things that I do not know (such as the maximum allowable voltage ripple of the load (in this case the MCU and the solid state MOS FET relay). I have gone through all of the relevant data sheets, but I can't make heads nor tails of this.

I am not asking someone to do my calculations for me or tell me what values and or parts to use. I just need some guidance on how to calculate these items.

ATTINY4-TS8R MCU data sheet:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/atmel-8127-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny4-attin-1065795.pdf

G3VM-61GR2 MOS FET relay data sheet:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/307/en-g3vm_61gr2-780127.pdf

AP1506-33K5G-13 DC-DC buck convertor data sheet:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/115/AP1506-464471.pdf

I also used this TVS diode to help protect the regulator from transients -
MMBZ15VALT116 TVS diode data sheet:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/348/mbz15val-e-1077132.pdf

Thank you for any guidance you can provide!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIeGVN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT - The schottky has been identified and the schematic corrected for that.

Comment: Thank you for that. Somehow I failed to make the connection because the diode in the schematic has a asterisk "*" by it and the "NOTE" is not indicated the same way. So, that answers that question! I'll look at an equivalent TI convertor data sheet and see if I can decipher the needed caps. **The comment I was responding to has disappeared...**

Comment: ... because I have made it an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diodes are listed at the bottom of page 2 in the data sheet and I would go and look at the TI equivalent chip because this will be much more supported in terms of documents. Here's a TI chip that runs at a lower frequency but, in all other aspects is largely identical. Side-by-side comparison: -

[image]

So, if Diodes Inc can't come up with the goods study the TI/Nat_semi design and get an idea about the capacitors. Whatever TI recommend for output capacitors you should consider that the Diodes Inc design runs at three times the frequency and hence can normally use one-third the capacitance for the same ripple voltage.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because I'm sure I can figure it out from here using the TI data sheet. Thank you!

Comment: Don't rule out that diodes inc can't support the design. I still do suggest you try and find a document on their website for this part but at least you have a back-up plan LOL.

Comment: Any chance you could explain what you mean by "can't support the design"?

Comment: I meant "can support" - too many negatives!